# Run a Python script on Heroku on schedule (as a separate app)

Tags: python, heroku, background-process

OK so I'm working on an app that has 2 Heroku apps - one is the writer that writes to my DB after scraping a site, and one is the reader that consumes the said DB.

The former is just a Python script that has a kind of a `while 1` loop - it's actually a Twitter stream. I want this to run every x minutes independent of what the reader is doing.

Now, running the script locally works fine, but I'm not sure how getting this to work on Heroku would work. I've tried looking it up, but could not find a solid answer. I read about background tasks, Redis queue, One-off dynos etc, but I'm not sure what to really use for my purpose. Some of my requirements are:

1. have the Python script keep logs of whatever I want.
2. in the future, I might want to add an admin panel for the writer, that will just show me stats of the script (and the logs). So hooking up this admin panel (flask) should be easy-ish and not break the script itself.

I would love any suggestions or pointers here.

Answer (score 3):

1. I suggest writing the consumer as a server that waits around, then processes the stream on the timed interval. That is, you start it once and it runs forever, doing some processing every 10 minutes or so.

   See: [sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) Python module, which handles scheduling events at certain times and running them.
2. Simpler: use Heroku's [scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) service.

This technique is simpler -- it's just straight-through code -- but can lead to problems if you have two of the same consumer running at the same time.